# How to prove that the derivative of a homogeneous equation is $y'=\frac{y}{x}$

Tags: calculus

I was solving a differential equation problem which required me to find out the derivative of.

> For the curve $x^2y^3=(2x+3y)^5$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y}{g(x)} $

The author simply stated that

> The derivative of a homogeneous equation is $y'=\frac{y}{x}$

I tried to verify this for $x^2+xy+y^2=0$$

But did not reach upon $y'=\frac{y}{x}$. The derivative will be $$y'=\frac{-(2x+y)}{(2y+x)}$$

**Is the statement valid only for some specific functions/polynomials. If that isn't the case what will be the proof for a general form?**

Comment: can you post the differential equation are you dealing with?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I had to find $g(x)$ for the curve mentioned in the question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true.

Consider the example you are giving.
$$y^2+yx+x^2=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow \Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)^2+\frac{y}{x}+1=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow 2\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)^2+\frac{2y}{x}+2=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{2\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)^2+\frac{2y}{x}+2}{\frac{2y}{x}+1}=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{y}{x}+\frac{\frac{y}{x}+2}{\frac{2y}{x}+1}=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow -\frac{\frac{y}{x}+2}{\frac{2y}{x}+1}=\frac{y}{x}$$
Now, LHS is the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ you are getting, which I have proved to be equal to as stated by the author.

Actually, any homogenous equation is an equation of the form
$$f(\frac{y}{x})=0$$
Differentiate both sides,
$$f'(\frac{y}{x})\times \frac{d}{dx}\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)=0$$
If $f'(\frac{y}{x})\neq 0$, then, by division rule,
$$\frac{x\times \frac{dy}{dx}-y}{x^2}=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x}$$

Hope it is helpful:)